# python updating each key value of dictionary in list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary in a list, and I am trying to iterate over the list and update dictionary key, value every after 10 seconds.

Example:

`list = [{"id": 3, "status": "pending"}, {"id": 4, "status": "pending"}, {"id": 2, "status": "pending"}]`

At a certain condition, I have another variable `global_status = executing or blocked or completed` based on **global_status**

```
if (global_status == executing ):
        output : [{"id": 3, "status": "routing"}, {"id": 4, "status": "pending"}, {"id": 2, "status": "pending"}]
    wait for 10 seconds
        output : [{"id": 3, "status": "completed"}, {"id": 4, "status": "routing"}, {"id": 2, "status": "pending"}]
    wait for 10 seconds
        output : [{"id": 3, "status": "completed"}, {"id": 4, "status": "completed"}, {"id": 2, "status": "completed"}]
```

Here I am iterating over the list, waiting for 10 seconds. Based on the `global_status`, update key, values of each dictionary separately in a sequential way.

Comment: What approach have you tried so far ?

Comment: i tried iterating over each dictionary key, value, but it updating all values, i am unable to understand how can we change different values each dictionary  in one iteration.

Comment: `for i in lst: i["status"] = "routing" ; print(lst) ; sleep(10) ; i["status"] = "completed"` Imports: [`sleep()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep).

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by, "change all dictionary values in one iteration" ?

Answer (score 0):

I made two fixes for your code.

First: You must have fixed pattern to use for loop.
I made an example pattern for you.

```
routing     pending     pending
completed   pending     pending

completed   routing     pending
completed   completed   pending

completed   completed   routing
completed   completed   completed
```

Second: You have to use two for loops to change each 'status' in each dictionary or it will change all of them.

```
import time
List = [{"id": 3, "status": "pending"}, {"id": 4, "status": "pending"}, {"id": 2, 
"status": "pending"}]
count = ['routing', 'completed'] # this is for your status

for i in List:
    for j in range(len(i)):
        i['status'] = count[j]
        print(List)
        time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: @Dharman, thank you understanding my expected result, only only thing i would like to ask, initially list will not be having any data, i have to fill the list data based on the existing data, please check below code  `waypoints_data = self.waypoints  waypoint_status_list = []
        for index, value in enumerate(waypoints_data): if (index == 0):
                waypoint_status={
                    "id": value["id"],
                    "status": "executing"
                }
                waypoint_status_list.insert(0, waypoint_status) `

Comment: index of 0 is routing/executing and rest of indexes i need to fill pending, which is nothing but **routing     pending     pending** and then so on **completed   pending     pending

completed   routing     pending
completed   completed   pending

completed   completed   routing
completed   completed   completed**
 i have to create the new object to fill into the empty list